# MVC 4 paging - Razor view

Tags: razor, paging

[image]

I am trying to add paging but having no luck.

**This is the view**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WS.Models.Category>


@{
ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.items_uri)
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

**And this is the controller**

```
using PagedList;

namespace WS.Controllers
{

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        List<Category> allCategories = categoryRepository.GetCategories();
        return View(allCategories.ToPagedList(1,25));
    }

}
}
```

if I use

```
@model IEnumerable<WS.Models.Category>
```

instead of

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WS.Models.Category>
```

everything works and I can access the model attributes but as I want to use paging, I need to model to contain paging properties. What's the wrong thing I am making? Any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you post the complete compiler error. It is cut-off in your image...

Comment: Oh sorry it says it doesn't contain items_uri